# Include entity return invalid lambda operation

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm currently using entity framework core so I'm creating a query to return a list of profiles.

My logic is: each profile has one user, so the users table has a profiled foreign key; my current code without users is:

```
var dataList = queryBase.Include(p => p.ProfileFiles)
                                    .Include(p => p.PersonSkills)
                                    .ThenInclude(ps => ps.Skill)
                                    .ToList();
```

This is working, now I want to include the user of each profile, so I change the profile entity with the user as:

```
    [NotMapped]
    public virtual ApplicationUser User  {get;set;}
```

And now include as:

```
var dataList = queryBase.Include(p => p.ProfileFiles)
                                        .Include(p => p.PersonSkills)
                                        .ThenInclude(ps => ps.Skill)
                                        .Include(u => u.User)
                                        .ToList();
```

But this is throwing an error:

> Message "Lambda expression used inside Include is not valid."

Why is it detected as invalid? Regards

Comment: User is not mapped. I.e. the property is not connected to the entity. By calling include you are trying to load related data from other tables related to the entity. But the property you are trying to connect isn't even mapped. So why would you include it.

Comment: Ohh, I understand; well, the target of this is to know if the profile already has a user, so what can I do to add to my query if each profile contains a related user? @JHBonarius

Comment: Your code doesn't show how User is filled in. It's not EFCore mapping data to it, so it must be user logic. That should add it.

Comment: `[NotMapped]` attribute is the problem, you should remove it if the `Profile.User` navigation property must be associated with the `Profile.UserId` FK